# How to read doc file using Poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to view word file in my editor pane 
I tried these lines

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class editorpane extends JEditorPane
{
public editorpane(File file)
{

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument hwpfd = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(hwpfd);
        String[] array = we.getParagraphText();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            this.setPage(array[i]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but gives me

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:138)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:174)
at frame1.editorpane.<init>(editorpane.java:24)
```

in this line

```
HWPFDocument hwpfd = new HWPFDocument(fis);
```

how can I solve that ??

beside I am not sure about these lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            this.setPage(array[i]);
        }
```

can I get them confirmed ??

Comment: Did you read the error messages? Did you try using XSSF instead of HSSF?

Comment: i couldnt find what is xssf or where to be replaced

Comment: Try XWPFDocument class. What's the type of the document? Is it a doc or docx file?

Comment: word in general (doc or docx)

Comment: If using XWPFDocument worked for you, then you will need to first determine the type of the document and then use both HWPFDocument and XWPFDocument classes respectively.

Comment: ok cant i use one for both ??
..and XWPFDocument doesnt work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open a .docx file (XWPF) with code for .doc (HWPF) files. You can use `XWPFWordExtractor` for .docx files.

There is an `ExtractorFactory` which you can use to let POI decide which of these applies and uses the correct class to open the file, however you can then not iterate by page as only a generic `getText()` method is available then.

Use it like this

```
POITextExtractor extractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(file);
extractor.getText();
```

Comment: it doesnt matter if i used XWPF or HWPF...i keep getting that error in the same line---> HWPFDocument hwpfd = new HWPFDocument(fis); or ---> XWPFDocument Xwpfd = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));

Comment: The stacktrace/error message when using XWPFDocument is surely different, or? Can you add that one to the question as well.

Comment: Yes, but the stacktrace, i.e. the code-locations where the program was at that time cannot be the same, because you are calling a method in completely different class, so please post that as well to let us see via which code-path you get the same error message.