# password protected doc and docx file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I want to protect doc and docx files with password using java. I have tried using Apache POI. But it can't help me out.I am not getting any file at the location How would I do that?
Any another way or API??

```
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            File file=new File("D:/abc.doc");
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("xxxxx");

            OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(file,PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
            OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
            opc.save(os);
            opc.close();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/abc12345.docs");
            fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            fos.close();
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701322/apache-poi-how-to-protect-sheet-with-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://www.quicklyjava.com/create-password-protected-excel-using-apache-poi/

Try this constructor for info object:

`EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);`

Comment: The constructor EncryptionInfo(POIFSFileSystem, EncryptionMode) is undefined

Comment: I have added a snapshot for the POI versions

Comment: Why are you recommending such old versions of Apache POI? Those ones are 4 years old!

Comment: sorry for late info....this is working only for docx format....when i tried it with doc it give me exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException:

Comment: Please do some googling around it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924676/how-to-read-doc-file-using-poi for example

Answer (score -2):

check this and try to adapt yourself
http://www.quicklyjava.com/create-password-protected-excel-using-apache-poi/

Comment: Please avoid link only answer.

Comment: tried but it can't help me out.....this code is running without error...but am not getting any file at the location

Comment: Could you try to change the output folder to your desktop.